# Saving multiple images to local storage from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my app connected to a firebase database and displays images I saved previously. They are retrieved from the database just fine and showed on my application's screen without issues. Furthermore, I want to save them while the application is running. I want them to be saved locally independent from my main activity life cycle so that they only be reloaded from local storage when the whole app is destroyed and started again.

```
 imageDownloadList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Images are downloading are loading please wait");
    progressDialog.show();

    mDatbaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FB_DATABASE_PATH);

    mDatbaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                ImageDownload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageDownload.class);
                imageDownloadList.add(img);
            }

            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(ImageViewActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imageDownloadList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

So this is what I have for getting the images. But how can I saved the array of images. So that would be the imageDownloadList arrayList.

Comment: Save how? Files, Sqlite? Firebase is cached locally, right?  Do you need to explicitly save anything?

Comment: Well every time I close the activity and it gets destoryed the images have to reload. I don't want the user having to reload all the images every time they start the activity once the app is running.
I'm really bad at explaining things.

So once the user destroys the whole app. All images that are stored locally get destroyed and have to be reloaded back into the app once they open it up again. If that makes sense

Comment: Just want to save the image files while app is running locally then remove them once the app is destroyed. Reload them when it's booted up again.

Comment: It's not clear what data is part of ImageDownload class. If you want to save Bitmap images to files, try to create a [mcve] of that using a single image. Then you can use that code in your Firebase stuff

Comment: I'll give a go and see what happens. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of a simple method is convert that image into a base64 string and save it using SharedPreferences or Sqlite. So when you open app again you can get that base64 string, convert to an image and show it.